# Why the url become like this(add ? before #) after redirecting and how can I redirect correctly

Tags: vue.js, redirect

I'm making a login page with redirect function,and the logic following like this:

if I never logged and I enter the url '/home/qiputranscode',it will redirect to

'http://127.0.0.1:8000/#/login?redirect=%2Fhome%2Fqiputranscode'.

then I need to request the server with username and pwd to get token for entry '/home/qiputranscode' page.

but after inputting my username and pwd the url become this:

'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?#/login?redirect=%2Fhome%2Fqiputranscode'

and didn't request the server or redirect to '/home/qiputranscode'.

so, why the url add ? in itself before #.

and what's difference between them, I will be grateful if u gave me any suggestion

the redirect code like this:

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 if (to.matched.some(r => r.meta.requiredAuth)) {
   if (store.state.token) {
     next()
   } else {
     next ({
       path: '/login',
       query: {redirect: to.fullPath}
     })
   }
 } else {
   next()
 }
});
```

Comment: The part after ? is the query with key redirect and value full path. To redirect here after login call `router.push({ path: this.$route.query.redirectTo })`. And seems like you need to prvent your form submitting with `<form v-on:submit.prevent`

Comment: @NaN your solution completely solved my problem, thank you so much!!

Comment: You're welcome. Made the answer from my comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The part after `?` is the `query` with `key=redirect` and `value=full path`

To redirect to the saved path call this after login

```
this.$router.push({ path: this.$route.query.redirectTo })
```

And you also need to prevent the default form behavior

```
<form v-on:submit.prevent ...
```